# Get a list of currently logged in users using C# or VB.NET

Tags: .net, wpf

I'm interested in getting a list of users that are currently logged in to the local machine using C# or VB.NET.

Basically I want to mimic the information displayed on the "Users" tab in the Task Manager (Windows 7).

Comment: are you using wpf or silverlight? that will change the answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get a list of local Windows users who are logged in?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194468/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-local-windows-users-who-are-logged-in)

Comment: I personally use Cassia, and recommend it.